How do you configure OpenSearch to allow finding exact matches with quotes
I'm trying to solve how an OpenSearch index and its mappings must be configured to allow searching with quotes to find an exact match of the search term.
Currently, all fields are of type text and no tokenizer or analyzer is defined on the index or the field mappings. So everything is default.
PUT /items/_mappings
{
      "properties": {
        ...
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
        ...
}

Search example 1: name=ABC returns items whose name contains "ABC". As expected.
Search example 2: name="ABC" currently returns a list of matches, including ABC but also ABC DEF EFG, ABC foo, bar ABC etc. So all items whose name CONTAINS "ABC" are also returned.
So how do I configure the index so that name="ABC" return only the item named 'ABC'?
Usually the search is done without the quotes, which correctly returns all items whose name contains "ABC". The quotes should tell OpenSearch to "please only give me the exact match".
I hope this makes sense. Thank you!

Hey John, are we talking about a DSL query, or are you asking for Opensearch dashboard discover?

@MusabDogan sorry for the delayed response, we are talking about an API call. The search in the application should find exact matches when using quotes ""

You're welcome @John. If you are looking for exact match you should disable use  untokenized/unanalyzed field which is keyword field. So yes, you must use "field.keyword="xxx" syntax.
|||||||||| In addition, it's recommended to use field.keyword with term query because it will tune the search latency.

Short answer: Use keyword field type for exact match.
In your case both name.keyword: ABC and name.keyword: "ABC" queries will only match with the exact term.

Here are some tips about elasticsearch/opensearch discover:

name: ABC is a match query.

name: "ABC" is a match_phrase query.


Text field type value ABC DEF EFG tokenized by standard tokenizer and become ABC and DEF and EFG because of that both name: ABC and name: "ABC" query will match with ABC DEF EFG document.
Keyword field type is untokenized, so ABC DEF EFG become ABC DEF EFG again.
Explanation with _analyzer API call.
#standard tokenizer for `text` field type
POST _analyze
{
  "text": "ABC DEF EFG",
  "tokenizer": "standard"
}

#standard tokenizer for `keyword` field type
POST _analyze
{
  "text": "ABC DEF EFG",
  "tokenizer": "keyword"
}



thanks. So does that mean every time the user wants an exact match using quotes, he must use the "field.keyword="xxx" syntax? Is there no other way?
